# Awesome_nested_set for ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Trying to install the awesome_nested_set gem for ruby 1.8.7 rails 2.3.8 environment

```
ERROR:  Error installing awesome_nested_set:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

How do i check what version is compatible with 1.8.7 ? 
Are there any other options for nested set structure ?

Comment: If you're running Rails 2.3.8 on a public site you are at **extreme risk**. Please [patch to 2.3.14](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/8/16/ann-rails-2-3-14/) immediately.

Comment: @tadman This is for a pet project not a public website.

Comment: Just saying. Super bad things can happen with .8 and upgrading to .14 is usually as easy as reinstalling the gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a historical version you can always install it with:

```
gem install awesome_nested_set -v x.x.x
```

Where `x.x.x` is an older version number. You can lock this down in your `Gemfile` as well.

Comment: I know how to install a gem but I need to check compatibility

Comment: You can let [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) try and find a compatible version. What I usually do is try different versions using a binary search to narrow down to the best possible match.